# Install Maven on Jenkins 1.651.3 using Apache

Tags: maven, jenkins

I want to install Maven on Jenkins. Now I can only choose 3.3.9 or older and not 3.5.0 (version which I need).

I'm on an older version of Jenkins (1.651.3). How can I sync this?

[image]

How can I get newer maven versions in my installer in Jenkins?

Comment: Update your maven plugin in Jenkins Plugin Manager or you can set the maven path of your system (if you have higher version i.e., 3.5.0)

Comment: I've upgraded the plugin + restarted but still no apache option. I know that setting the path will help, but we want to follow a general way.